# What does "Deux précautions valent mieux qu'une" mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, proverbes

I guess this means “two precautions are better than one” or “better safe than sorry”.

What does “valent” mean? It doesn't derive from *être*, but seems to be acting like “sont” in this case?

Comment: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/valoir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the infinitive [*“valoir”*](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/valoir.html) ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/valoir)), meaning *“to be equivalent to”* or *“to be worth”*.

*“Valoir mieux que”* means *“to be better than”* or *“to be worth more than”*.

The form *“valent”* is the third person plural of the present tense.

Comment: I feel stupid now, I know that verb! But haven't used in in 3rd person plural too much. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No need to feel bad about this. If you more commonly encountered the singular conjugations, for which the L has been dropped and replaced by a U, it can be tricky to recognize it in this form the first time.

Comment: One more question about this, what other verbs ending in 'oir' are conjugated in a similar way to vouloir and valoir?

Comment: I could think of *“falloir”*, which is common, but only ever used in the singular third person. More research revealed also *“équivaloir”, “prévaloir”*, and the very rare and very aged [*“challoir”*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaloir). Not very many, it looks like.